# E/Unity: DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0':[Solved]

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I built a unity game with firebase, then I exported it and integrated it to an existing Android app as an ARR file format.

Everything was great and integrated, but the firebase in unity was not connected (it connected and worked as expected without integrating with the Android app).

This error appears in the run console, without crashing just the firebase not connected
[Error in run console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ4Ym.png)
please, I really need your help

a big thanks in advance! :)

---

I successfully solved the problem by simply search about the package 'FirebaseCppApp-7_1_0' in the launcher that unity exported(to launch the game as a standalone Android app ). Then I take the lib of that package and put them in the same folder in my existing app.

That's up!

Comment: Hi, you should post your error as code not the screenshot. Just get the text from your error and post it in your question.

Answer (score 3):

This style of application (Unity as a library) is not well tested in the Firebase SDK. I would ask that you [open up a bug here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues) so the team can prioritize official support on the roadmap (and I'm sure they'd like your feedback).

With that out of the way, it looks like you're missing some native libraries. Specifically, you're missing the files that are stored in `Firebase/m2repository`. Since I don't know the details of how a Unity project is exported, I have a number of things you can try.

First, figure out what you need in your gradle project for your Android app. The easiest way to do this would be to open up your "Publishing Settings" and checking "Custom Main Gradle Template" and "Custom Gradle Properties Template":
[image: Screenshot of the Publishing Settings window with the Custom templates selected]

Then force resolve dependencies to make sure your `Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle` file gets updated:
[image: Screenshot of the Unity menu open to "Assets>External Dependency Manager>Android Resolver>ForceResolve"]

If you then open up your `Assets/Plugins/Android/mainTemplate.gradle` you will have something like this at the top:

```
maven {
    url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/GeneratedLocalRepo/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/RemoteConfigDependencies.xml:20
}
```

and a list of dependencies that the resolver found somewhere bleow. Mine looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
// Android Resolver Dependencies Start
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/RemoteConfigDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:7.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.5.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:20.0.3' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/RemoteConfigDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-unity:7.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/RemoteConfigDependencies.xml:20
// Android Resolver Dependencies End
**DEPS**}
```

So I suspect that the dependencies are not being clearly transmitted across, specifically the `*-unity` ones that provide the C++ implementations of Firebase features. I feel like this should have been a build error, but again I'm not familiar with the "Unity as a Library" process. Things to try:

1. in your target project, make sure you add the maven URL for the local m2 repository. This way you can find the m2 dependencies you need.
2. in your target project, add the dependencies that the dependency manager injects into the Unity gradle project. To ensure that you have everything in your build.

There are two important items to note:

1. the `maven` URL is absolute. You might have to get tricky with gradle to reliably specify this across machines in your dev environment.
2. these dependencies will change every Firebase SDK release *and* must be kept in sync with each other. So if you have to copy anything from the bottom section, you'll have to do it manually every time.

Answer (score 1):

you might have mixed Firebase dependencies, try deleting your Unity Library and rebuild the project. It worked for me